# Iterate through hashable containing list of values and iterate through each value in the list

Tags: powershell, office365

I am working on a script I can run that will take a list of users and their allocated licenses and filter them based on their UPN to get a count of license usage per sub domain as a representation of the total licenses.

I have sorted them into hash tables based on the domain in their UPN.

```
$org1Users += [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
            AccountSkuId = $user.Licenses
```

With those hash tables each contains the UPN and the Licenses string for each user displayed as:

```
UserprincipalName            Licenses
-----------------                      --------
Bob_Frank@domain.com        {org:STREAM, org:ENTERPRISEPACK}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can iterate through each user in the hashtable and split out their licenses so that I can do a switch or if/else chain of "if they have x license" increment the count of *License_Type" in another Hashtable.
As it is it will only do it once per user which doesn't work if they have Multiple Licenses.

```
foreach($user in $AGUsers)
{
If($AGUsers.AccountSkuId -eq 'owfg:VISIOCLIENT')
    {
        $ConsumedLicenses[$VISIOCLIENT]++
    }
    elseif ($AGUsers.AccountSkuId -eq "org:STREAM" ) {
        $ConsumedLicenses[$STREAM]++
    }
.....onwards
```

At the end I will be taking the values from the License_Type hash tables and using the individual values to generate a report breaking down the % of the total count of licenses each domain is consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure of the data, you'll probably need two loops to "pivot" the data, and one loop to determine percentages.

The first loop should go over each user.

The second loop should go over each license.

Personally, I'd use another hashtable to "pivot" the data so that you end up with a hashtable of licenses and users.  I'd also keep track of the total as I go, because that saves the effort of doing it later when calculating a percentage.

```
$licenseTotal = 0
$groupedByLicense = @{}
foreach ($user in $agusers) {
   foreach ($userLicense in $agUsers.AccountSkuID) {
       if (-not $groupedByLicense[$userLicense]) {
           $groupedByLicense[$userLicense] = @()
       }
       $groupedByLicense[$userLicense] += $user
       $licenseTotal++
   }
}

# In the second loop, we'll walk over each key/value in a Hashtable.
# To do this, you'll want to use .GetEnumerator
$licensePercentage = @{}
foreach ($keyValuePair in $groupedByLicense.GetEnumerator()) {
    $licensePercentage[$keyValuePair.Key] = # FYI
       # you can break assignments into multiple lines
       $keyValuePair.Value.Length / 
       # comments can exist after an operator
       $licenseTotal

}

[PSCustomObject]$LicensePercentage
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Terminology note**: `[PSCustomObject]@{ ... }` is a *custom-object literal*, not a [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables). That is, even though this form of *syntactic sugar* is based on a *hashtable* literal (`@{ ... }`), it constructs a `[pscustomobject]` instance.
- To test if an *array* of values *contains* a value of interest (based on equality testing, i.e. per-element `-eq` tests), use the [`-contains`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains).

Thus, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
switch ($AGUsers)
{
  { $_.AccountSkuId -contains 'owfg:VISIOCLIENT' } { $ConsumedLicenses[$VISIOCLIENT]++ }
  { $_.AccountSkuId -contains 'owfg:STREAM' }      { $ConsumedLicenses[$STREAM]++ }
  # ...
}
```

Note that - unlike an `if ... elseif ...` statement - the conditionals of a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) are *all* evaluated by default, unless you short-circuit processing with `continue` (if you were to use `break` all remaining `$AGUsers` elements would be skipped).

Comment: I had to do some fiddling since my input values were not sanitized. 
It worked after I stopped declaring initial values in the PScustom Object and changing the $Value to 'Value' in the Switch Statement.